# Compute prime in haskell

Tags: haskell, primes

I wish to compute whether a given integer is prime in Haskell:

```
--primes
isPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
isPrime n | n < 4 = n > 1
isPrime n = all ((/=0).mod (n-1)) $ 2:3:[x + i | x <- [6,12..s], i <- [-1,1]]
            where s = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n
```

However, running this on the input `131` gives `False`. I think the error lies in modular arithmetic but I'm not sure. Is there anything wrong with the modular statement in my program?

Comment: Why are you checking that `n-1` is not a multiple of any possible prime? Don't you want to use `n` instead?

Comment: @ErikR oops! you're right, good catch. That fixed it!